# Heap Sort : how to correct my coding and to implement my logic?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

for an array input 2 5 8 3 4 6
i am getting 2 4 5 3 8 6
i am trying to implement heap sort and i am a beginner and i don't know what error comes here and i am simply trying to implement the logic of heap sort just by building a heap and interchanging the last element with the the largest first index element and thereby decreasing the size of the array.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<conio.h>
```

to build a get the highest element in the starting index

```
  heapify(int *a,int i,int no)
  {

      int largest = i;
      int left = 2*i;
      int right = 2*i+1;
      if(left<=no && a[left]>largest)
      {
        largest=left;
      }

      if(right<=no && a[right]>largest)
      {
          largest=right;
      }

      if(largest!=i)
      {
          int temp=a[largest];      
          a[largest]=a[i];
          a[i]=temp;
          heapify(a,largest,no);
      }
  }
```

to heap sort the elements in the array and

```
  heapsort(int *a,int no)
  {
      while(no>1)
      {
          int temp=a[1];
          a[1]=a[no];
          a[no]=temp;
          --no;
          heapify(a,1,no);
      }
  }
```

to print the lements in the array

```
  printarr(int *a,int no)
  {
      int i=1;

      for(;i<=no;i++)
          printf("%d",a[i]);      
  }
```

this is the main function.

```
  int main()
  {
      int i,j,k,no,size;

      printf("Enter the no of elements");
      scanf("%d",&no);
      int a[no+1];
      size=no;

      for(i=1;i<=no;i++)
      {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
      }

      printarr(a,no);
      j=no/2;

      for(i=j;i>0;--i)
      {
        heapify(a,i,no);
      }

      heapsort(a,no);
      printarr(a,no);

      getch();

      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn how to use your debugger. If you don't have a debugger then there are plenty of options, or you can just use the "strategic printf" debugging method.

Comment: thanks for remainding me @PaulR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the index with array value in heapify function

```
 if(left<=no && a[left]>largest)
```

and

```
if(right<=no && a[right]>largest)
```

This shuold be

```
 if(left<=no && a[left]>a[largest])
```

and

```
if(right<=no && a[right]>a[largest])
```